# Using Bayes' Theorem twice? Stats Problem

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics

Given: $P(A) / P(B) = 0.1$, $P(O|A) = 0.9$, $P(O|B) = 0.5$

Find the ratio of conditional probability of A, to the conditional probability of B in each case conditioned by O.

I understand Bayes' theorem denotes:
$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A)P(B|A)}{P(B)},$$

but I am not sure how I can utilize $P(A)/P(B) = 0.1$ to find $P(O)$? Anyone have an idea or tips?

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like either a homework or a self-study question. Have you tried writing the question out? In other words, what is the expression you are being asked to find? Given that, what steps have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

$$P(A|O) = \frac{P(A)P(O|A)}{P(O)}$$

It might seems that you have to know $P(O)$ but actually you don't have to.

What you should do is to write down a similar expression for $P(B|O)$, of which $P(O)$ will also appear in the denominator.

When you compute the ratio of $P(A|O)$ and $P(B|O)$, $P(O)$ will get cancel out.